# Definition of a complex space

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

A complex analytic subset of a complex manifold $M$ is a closed subset which is locally defined as common zeros of finitely manly analytic functions. A complex space is a second countable Hausdorff topological space equipped with an open cover $\{U_{i}\}$, where each $U_i$ is homemomorphic to a complex analytic subset of $\mathbb C^{n_i}$. (The definition is taken from [Demailly's complex analytic and differential geometry, page 101](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf).

Question: 1). Analytic subsets are closed subsets of complex manifolds, but on complex spaces they are open, which feels a little strange. What is going on here? 2). How to define the notion of holomorphic function on a complex space?

Comment: A. Can you clarify question 1? I don't understand "they are open", since nothing you quoted seems to say that an analytic subset is open.
B. Please do not use the quote feature of markdown for emphasis.

Comment: The definition requires $U_i$ to be an open cover of the space.

Comment: So what? That's a chart for the big space. The analytic subset is still (locally) closed, being defined as zeroes of continuous functions.

Comment: Well, it is certainly locally closed. On the other hand, at least from the definition per se, it is not necessarily closed in the topology of the ambient space. But in the definition of an analytic subset it is required explicitly that an analytic subset must be closed in the topology of the ambient space. I guess my question is why one requires the analytic subset to be closed.

Comment: That's correct, the $U_i$ are not closed in $M$, nor would you want them to be. These are two totally different types of sets under discussion; that is to say, the sets $U_i$ which occur in an open cover of a manifold are not analytic subsets. To define holomorphicity here, let $f:M \to\mathbb C$ be a function, and let $\varphi_i:V_i \to U_i$ be homeomorphisms, where each $V_i \subset \mathbb C^{n_i}$. Then $f_i := (f|_{U_i})\circ \varphi_i:V_i \to \mathbb C$ is a function from (an open subset of) complex Euclidean space to $\mathbb C$...

Comment: ...and we know when such a thing is holomorphic. We say $f$ is holomorphic if each $f_i$ is. Now analytic subsets are those defined by the vanishing of one or more holomorphic functions on $M$, and analytic subsets are just closed because $\left\{0\right\}\subset\mathbb C$ is closed and holomorphic functions are continuous, hence $f^{-1}(0) \subset M$ is closed.

Comment: If your real question is "why one requires the analytic subset to be closed", you should edit the question accordingly, not keep it buried among comments. Chirka in his book also defines "local" analytic subsets, which are not required to be closed. One can prove some results for such subsets, but much less than in the case of closed analytic subsets.